# Quickly move the tab focus to the content in Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, accessibility

When you press enter on the omnibar, the focus switches to the web page content. This is great, but what if you have switched to the omnibar and want to switch back to the web page?

Hitting tab cycles through the Chrome extension buttons, then the bookmarks, (then something hidden to the right of the bookmarks(?)), then finally the web page. The other direction goes to reload, forward, back, then to the last link of the web page.

Is there a shortcut to move the focus directly to the web page from the omnibar, and preferably from any focusable point?

Comment: So looking for the reverse of F6 which switches the focus to the omnibar.

Comment: What version of chrome are you using?  When I hit <kbd>tab</kbd> from the omnibar I am taken to the first link on the page.  <kbd>Shift-tab</kbd> takes me to the last.

Comment: @DanD. Yes, exactly

Comment: @Paul OS X 19.0.1084.46 beta -- Do you have extensions and the bookmark bar visible?

Comment: Yes I do... see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, it appears to be different depending how you get to the omnibar.  If you hit <kbd>F6</kbd> to get to the omnibar, then tab steps through the interface elements.

If you use <kbd>ctrl-L</kbd> to get to the omnibar, then tab steps through the page content links.

Comment: Interesting. F6 doesn't seem to be valid in OS X: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=22012

Comment: In OS X, cmd-L does not work as you describe. I realise that wasn't the original question, but it would be good for an answer to cover Windows and OS X.

Comment: @GeraldKaszuba If F6 worked, then hitting repeatedly would get you back to webcontent, but you are right it isn't an OSX shortcut.  I don't suppose cmd-L will get you back with a second hit?

Comment: Cmd-L just keeps the focus in the omnibar. Maybe a bug report is in order.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Paul's answer:

If you have bookmark bar pinned, press F6 twice from omnibar.

If not, one F6 will get you to webpage.

I have not tested on Mac because I don't have one..

Kindly test and reply.

Also try Cmd-Shift-L

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F10</kbd> twice works from any focusable point(including extension popups, devtool)

Except when these are open.

- right-click menus
- three-dot menus and the likes
- the notification popup

<kbd>Esc</kbd> cancels the the notification popup.

If this does't work, <kbd>F6</kbd> focuses the popup and
can be closed using <kbd>Tab</kbd>s or <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

This normally focus the page.

If it doesn't, pressing `F10` twice will probably work.

P.S. This gives me nerves, so despite this question is really old, I put this here just in case someone got here.